# Why does the following code works with one model but doesn't work with another?

Tags: javascript, php

I was trying to preview the image using javascript but its not working for all the modal ie it works for one modal and doesn't work for other modal. Javascript id selector selects the the same id in all the modal as well. Is this a problem of javascript or is my code wrong somewhere? For the values of constants like $i and others, they have been already defined as well.

```
<?php foreach($bannerDatas as $key=>$value){ ?>

  <td>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default actionBtnPic" 
                title="Edit" 
                data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#myModalUpload<?php echo $z; $z++;?>"  
                style="border-radius: 25%;" > Change Pic </a>

  </td>

<?php } ?>

<?php $j=1; foreach ($bannerDatas as $key=>$value): ?>

  <div class="modal fade" 
       id="myModalUpload<?php echo $j; $j++;?>" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

          <button type="button" class="close" 
                                data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

          <h4 class="modal-title" 
              style="padding: 2rem 0;">Upload New Picture</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">

              <form class="form form-horizontal" 
                    action="controller/banner" method="post">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Change with</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">

                    <input type = "file" name="images" 
                           id="file-upload" accept="image/*">

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                      <?php echo ucfirst($act); ?>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">

              <img id="blah" src="#" a
                   lt="your image" class="img img-responsive" />

            </div>
          </div>

          <script type="text/javascript">

              function readURL(input) {
                  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                      var reader = new FileReader();
                      reader.onload = function (e) {
                          $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                      }
                      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                  }
              }
              $("#file-upload").change(function(){
                  readURL(this);
              });

          </script>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: the `id` must be unique in the whole page. If there are several identical ids, only the first one will ever be selected. Use classes instead

Comment: `function readURL(input) {` Is being duplicated.  Please remove the function from the foreach loop.

Comment: `<?php echo $z; $z++;?>` please [read up how the increment/decrement operators work](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others are saying, `id` has to be uniq and can only exist once.
instead create a wrapper and append each image instead

Also suggest you use URL.createObjectURL instead of using the FileReader

```js
function readURL(input) {
  var files = Array.from(input.files)

  files.forEach(function(file){
    var img = new Image()
    img.className = 'img img-responsive'

    img.onload = function() {
      $('#previews').append(img)

      // revoke if you don't need the url for something else
      URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src)
    }
    img.onerror = function(){
      // not an image
    }
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
  }}
}

$("#file-upload").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<div id="previews"></div>
```